# Nodejs node-schedule npm is throwing error "this.job.execute is not a function"

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, npm

I'm new to nodejs and I have written a nodejs program and scheduling it every minute using the node-schedule. but after running for some time and generating a couple of logs at the console, nodejs throws error that `this.job.execute is not a function`

here is the code I am using:

```
var nodeSchedule = require('node-schedule');

runJob();

function runJob(){
    console.log("start");
    nodeSchedule.scheduleJob('0 * * * * *',require('./prodModules.js'));

}
```

the logs I am getting is:

```
C:\Users\1060641\Downloads\NodeJS HealthReport\Collector>node src\main\nodejs\collector_main.js
start
Connected
Ready
logged in as Super User
nfs_check running...
NFS Check completed
snapchart_check running...
C:\Users\1060641\node_modules\node-schedule\lib\schedule.js:177
    this.job.execute();
             ^

TypeError: this.job.execute is not a function
    at Job.invoke (C:\Users\1060641\node_modules\node-schedule\lib\schedule.js:177:14)
    at null._onTimeout (C:\Users\1060641\node_modules\node-schedule\lib\schedule.js:445:11)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:92:15)

C:\Users\1060641\Downloads\NodeJS HealthReport\Collector>
```

I don't think there is anything wrong with my `prodModules.js` since running it standalone its running fine.
Scheduling is throwing errors.

Please help.

Comment: If you think it is an error with the library, so check out the issues in github. That's where I'd look first.

Comment: are you sure `require('./prodModules.js')` returns what you think it does? and is it what `scheduleJob` is expecting as a second parameter?

Comment: @Kevin-B : you were right. I didnt envelop the prodModules.js in a function, and calling the js file, thats why it was throwing the error that prodModules is not a function. So I wrapped the whole code in prodModules.js in a export.myFunc=function(){} and its working fine now.
Thanks Kevin for hinting :)

Answer (score 3):

The node-scheduler callback must be a function.
Change your runJob to something like this:

```
function runJob() {
    console.log("start");
    nodeSchedule.scheduleJob('0 * * * * *', function () { 
        require('./prodModules.js');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try re-importing 'node-schedule',  I ran your code with a fresh import, and it works as expected.

To down import on windows cmd : > npm install node-schedule